# ProcessBatchData returns ErrorText:Invalid text value

Tags: batch

ProcessBatchData returns error:

```
Id:1 Code:-2130575336 ItemId:0 ErrorText:Invalid text value. 
A text field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.Id:2 Code:-2147023673 ItemId:0 ErrorText:The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred. (Result Code: 0x800704c7)
```

Does anybody know what this error means?

Comment: please, provide you code for batch data.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was with setting SP Title field with value which length exceeds 255 characters restriction.